# Incremented JavaScript variable is not passing as the parameter

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {



    var $item = $('div.imgItem'), //Cache your DOM selector
        visible = 1, //Set the number of items that will be visible
        index = 0, //Starting index
        endIndex = ( $item.length / visible ) - 1, //End index
        imgIndex = 1; 

    $('div#imageItem' + imgIndex).click(function(){
        if (index == 0 || index == (endIndex-1))
        {
            var animatePX = imgWidth * .85 + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            var animatePX = imgWidth * .9 + 2;
        }

        if(index < endIndex ){
          index++;
          imgIndex++;
          //alert (imgIndex);
          $item.animate({'left':'-='+animatePX});
        }
    });

});
```

I am trying to create a slideshow.. my problem is that the variable imgIndex is incrementing inside the function, but second time the function is called, still the value of imgIndex is 0..
can someone help me on this.. 
i want the incremented value to be passed as the parameter each time..

@jfriend00 here is my html

```
<div class="imgItem" id="imgItem0">
</div>
<div class="imgItem" id="imgItem1">
</div>
<div class="imgItem" id="imgItem2">
</div>
<div class="imgItem" id="imgItem3">
</div>
<div class="imgItem" id="imgItem4">
</div>
```

an image will be loaded inside each div.. as I am creating a slider, i want to click the next image to slide it.. that's why I am using different id's for the div..

now can you tell me how i should change this line

```
$('div#imageItem' + imgIndex).click(function(){
```

Comment: Rather than doing $('div#imageItem' + imgIndex).click(function(){ I'd do it based on a class name and then use $(this) to get the id.

Comment: `$('div#imageItem' + imgIndex)` will always bind the click event to only `$('div#imageItem1')` as the binding only happens once the page is loaded.

Comment: @AhuSon - do you realize that on Stackoverflow, you are not supposed to add "Solved" to your title.  Instead, you are supposed to click the green checkmark next to the best answer.  This rewards the person who provided the answer, indicates to future readers which answer best answered your question and earns you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code:

```
$('div#imageItem' + imgIndex).click(function(){
```

appears to be the only line of code that is using `imgIndex` and it's only run once so it will only be executed once with that initial value of `0` for `imgIndex`.

If you want it to execute multiple times, then you'd either need to execute it again in the `.click()` handler or create a `for` loop to execute it multiple times with multiple values or you'd need to setup a different type of event handling where your initial event handler works for many objects.

We'd have to see your HTML and understand more about what you're trying to accomplish to know which path is best.

---

If you want click handlers for multiple objects, then it's probably best to put a common class name on them so you can set up the event handler like this:

```
$('.imageItemCommon').click(function(){{/* code here */});
```

Or, if these are dynamically created elements, then use delegated event handling:

```
$(static parent selector).on('.iamgeItemCommon', 'click', function() {/* code here */});
```

---

P.S.  There's no reason to use `'div#imageItem0'` instead of just `'#imageItem0'` as a selector.  Adding the 'div' part just slows down the selector engine and since ids are unique in the document anyway, you shouldn't need it as part of the filter.

---

OK, now that you've shown the actual HTML, I would suggest you use this form of the event handler as this will work for all the slides (no need for an id):

```
// advance to next slide on click
$(".imgItem").click(function() {
    // use $(this) to refer to the currently clicked on slide

});
```

---

And, here's what I think is simpler way to do this sort of animation:

```
var imgsNum = $(".imgItem").length
var imgWidth = 200;

$(".slideHolder").click(function() {
    var holder = $(this);
    var slideNum = -parseInt(holder.css("left"), 10) / imgWidth;
    if ((slideNum + 1) < imgsNum) {
        holder.animate({left: "-=" + imgWidth + "px"}, 1000);
    } else {
        holder.animate({left: "0"}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Demo with HTML and CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/AZ7NY/

Comment: i have edited the question and added the html code.. now can u please look into it..

Comment: @AhuSon - I've added the type of event handler I would recommend to the end of my answer.  I don't understand exactly what your code is trying to do so I didn't attempt to rewrite it all using this new form.  But, the point is that you use one common event handler for all your slides and you use `this` or `$(this)` to refer to the currently clicked on slide.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector:

```
$('div#imageItem' + imgIndex)
```

Is only created once, when `imgIndex=1`. You need to create something more general:

```
$('div[id^=imageItem]').click(function(){
    if ('imageItem'+imgIndex === this.id) {
        if (index == 0 || index == (endIndex-1))
        {
            var animatePX = imgWidth * .85 + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            var animatePX = imgWidth * .9 + 2;
        }

        if(index < endIndex ){
          index++;
          imgIndex++;
          //alert (imgIndex);
          $item.animate({'left':'-='+animatePX});
        }
    }
});
```